# problem loading blackberry application on playbook

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

i successfully created the .bar file and deployed in playbook simulator. i could see the icon of my application in the playbook simulator but when i click to open the application in playbook simulator it show a loading screen with white background and after a moment the player freezes without and error or warning. Did anyone faced the same problem and resolved the issue???? Please reply if anyone got the solution

Comment: I remember hitting a problem like this when I first started testing, I can't remember offhand what I had done wrong.  Are you using the WebWorks SDK?  If so, how did you create your app?  If you created a config.xml file can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

That's an inadequate description of the problem.  The "player freezes"... where?  On the loading screen?  After your main class displays?  Between the two somehow?

Also, you can compile with debug mode enabled and deploy while running the debugger.  Then you're very likely to see a traceback showing the specific error, instead of whatever this "freeze" is showing you.

Comment: Thankz for replying. I got the solution. Since i was using beta 3 webworks sdk and 0.9.3 simulator there was a incompatibility.i got it working when i run the app in 0.9.4 simulator.